# With node.js HTTP, how does res.end() guarantee a disconnection of the socket?

Tags: http, node.js, httprequest

This is node.js' `end` implementation:

```
OutgoingMessage.prototype.end = function(data, encoding) {
  if (this.finished) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!this._header) {
    this._implicitHeader();
  }

  if (data && !this._hasBody) {
    console.error('This type of response MUST NOT have a body. ' +
                  'Ignoring data passed to end().');
    data = false;
  }

  var ret;

  var hot = this._headerSent === false &&
            typeof(data) === 'string' &&
            data.length > 0 &&
            this.output.length === 0 &&
            this.connection &&
            this.connection.writable &&
            this.connection._httpMessage === this;

  if (hot) {
    // Hot path. They're doing
    //   res.writeHead();
    //   res.end(blah);
    // HACKY.

    if (this.chunkedEncoding) {
      var l = Buffer.byteLength(data, encoding).toString(16);
      ret = this.connection.write(this._header + l + CRLF +
                                  data + '\r\n0\r\n' +
                                  this._trailer + '\r\n', encoding);
    } else {
      ret = this.connection.write(this._header + data, encoding);
    }
    this._headerSent = true;

  } else if (data) {
    // Normal body write.
    ret = this.write(data, encoding);
  }

  if (!hot) {
    if (this.chunkedEncoding) {
      ret = this._send('0\r\n' + this._trailer + '\r\n'); // Last chunk.
    } else {
      // Force a flush, HACK.
      ret = this._send('');
    }
  }

  this.finished = true;

  // There is the first message on the outgoing queue, and we've sent
  // everything to the socket.
  if (this.output.length === 0 && this.connection._httpMessage === this) {
    debug('outgoing message end.');
    this._finish();
  }

  return ret;
};
```

Source: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L645

Apparently, the connection is only "finished" when `output.length === 0`.

So, if there is still data waiting to be written, and the receiving client for some reason is dodgy about receiving this data, will the request ever be ended?

I have also seen such issue where an end is not effective while trying to end a http request made by a flash uploader. I ended up doing the following, which did help:

```
    res.end(failureJSON, 'utf8');
    req.once('end', function _destroyConn() {
        req.connection.destroy();
    });
```

Seems very hackish. Anyway, is such behavior with `req.connection.destroy` needed to guarantee a disconnection from the socket?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, `res.end()` does not directly “guarantee a disconnection of the socket” because it needs to account for HTTP Keep-Alive. According to the docs, `end` tells the server that everything has been sent, and that the response is complete. It’s entirely up to the server object whether or not to disconnect immediately.

To answer your question more specifically, the important thing is that the response needs to emit a `finish` event. If you take a look at the implementation of `_finish()`, it pretty much just emits the event.

As you noted though, it doesn’t always call `_finish()` directly…but it **did** set `this.finished = true`. When `_flush()` executes, it sends any remaining data and THEN calls `_finish()`.

It’s kind of complicated, and I don’t think I can go into any more detail without the risk of being wrong.

As far as connections sometimes not closing, have you checked if you have `keep-alive` configured properly? If the HTTP connection is set up with `keep-alive` by default, then calling `end` will not close the socket.

If your print out `res.shouldKeepAlive`, it will tell you if your server is trying to use `keep-alive`. Set it to `false` at the start of your request handler if you want to stop the server from doing this.

Comment: What if the client claims that the connection is keep alive? I'm thinking the Flush command is not called because the client is preventing it (eg. by sending data).

Comment: If I'm reading it right, setting `res.shouldKeepAlive = false;` should override any client settings.

Comment: so your conclusion is that to properly end a connection is to execute the following sequence? ```res.shouldKeepAlive = false; res.end();```

Comment: Is there any specific way to force the socket to close?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I would appreciate it if you could answer my last question. :)

Comment: @Fosco I guess `req.connection.destroy()` but it is not part of the official API.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps you as I am building my framework for node 4.4+ but I have confirmed that you can send `Connection: close` header in your response to get node to close the connection.

```
let res = getResponseSomehow()

res.statusCode = 408
res.setHeader("Connection", "close")
res.end()
```

Also your destroy code could use the following tweak:

```
// First we give node the time to close the connection
// We can give it 2 seconds
let socket = getSocketSomehow();
let timer = setTimeout(function() {
  socket.destroy();
}, 2000);

socket.on("close", function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

I'm not quite sure if it's the **close** event you want. I normally try to use a library and stay away from the `net` api so this is just a guess.